# variable is not defined no-undef in React-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parameters, onclick, react-component

I was following **Mosh Hamedani**'s tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ke90Tje7VS0&t=1542s)  for creating **react-app**.

I did exactly what he said.

I'm trying to pass an argument called `product` to a function which is called for `onClick` 
However, I'm getting an error for which I didn't find much info.

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  formatCount() {
    return this.state.count === 0 ? "Zero" : this.state.count;
  }

  handleIncrement = product => {
    console.log(product);
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <span className={this.formatSpan()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
        <button
          onClick={() => this.handleIncrement(product)}
          className="btn btn-primary"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```

Here's the error:

> Failed to compile.
>
> ./src/components/counter.jsx   Line 41:  'product' is not defined 
>   no-undef
>
> Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.

Comment: In the code `onClick={() => this.handleIncrement(product)}` the variable product is not defined

Comment: `{() => this.handleIncrement(product)}` product is not defined in this scope

Comment: Ok. But how did it work in the tutorial where he didn't define the variable `product`?

Comment: @Underoos did you find the fix

Comment: Nope. Not found.

Answer (score 2):

Following that same tutorial, I had the same problem. What I understand is that the "product" here is refering to the event. Like H_R_S suggested, using this code:

```
handleIncrement = (product) => {
    console.log(product);
    this.setState({count : this.state.count + 1});
}

render() {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <span className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>{this.formatCount()}</span>
            <button onClick={(product) => this.handleIncrement(product)} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Increment</button>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

you will be able to see the event in the console :

[Result in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqqnl.png)

Answer (score 1):

you are passing product as variable which is not defined
pass parameter with inverted comas other wise declare it and assing a value.

use

```
onClick={() => this.handleIncrement("product")}
```

Answer (score 0):

product was never defined in your component. therefor it is not defined.
you can declare product in your component state, or pass a product to the component as a prop.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me:

```
onClick={(product) => this.handleIncrement(product)}
```